# Crontab wont run scripts

Tags: python, bash, cron

I have a light show on my raspberry pi. I also have crontab running to automate it. When I run the script in terminal it acts normally and works flawless. When cron runs it wont work correctly. I have it set to turn the lights off 15 sec before the show, run the show, 15 seconds later turn them back on. Now when the job runs it only plays the show and the relays never trigger to keep the lights on or off. I have 3 scripts. One is the show and 2 are turning the lights on and off. I'm really confused here.

Run the show

```
/home/pi/lightshowpi/./lightsoff.sh
sleep 15
$SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/bin/start_playlist_once $SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME/mus$
sleep 15
/home/pi/lightshowpi/./lightson.sh
```

Lights on

```
#!/bin/bash
export SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME=/home/pi/lightshowpi
python py/hardware_controller.py --config=overmech.cfg --state=on
```

Lights off

```
#!/bin/bash    
export SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME=/home/pi/lightshowpi   
python py/hardware_controller.py --config=overmech.cfg --state=off
```

All these are `.sh` files with `chmod +x`. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what is happening? If you run that first script manually it all works, but if you run it via crontab then the `lightsoff.sh` and `lightson.sh` scripts don't run? Is that right?

Comment: The cron job is running `python py/hardware_controller.py` -- are you sure the job is executed in the correct directory where `py/...` is available? Probably better to use absolute filenames or add a `cd <target-directory>` command at the beginning of the script

Comment: You miss the most important part, you crontab config

Comment: Crontab needs absolute paths to execute

Comment: That is what's happening. If I trigger the on and off manually it works. The directory it's all in is /home/pi/lightshowpi

Comment: @TimothyGrant - could you please post the output of `crontab -l` for us? This is what Wonka was referring to.

Comment: Here is the crontab file

SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME=/home/pi/lightshowpi

0 18,19,20,21,22  * * * /home/pi/lightshowpi/lightshow.sh

30 17 * * * /bin/bash /home/pi/lightshowpi/lightson.sh  2&>1 >> lights_on_log.txt

30 22 * * * /bin/bash /home/pi/lightshowpi/lightsoff.sh  2&>1 >> lights_off_log.txt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what PATH cronjobs run with, but it may be that it's not finding the `python` executable. Try putting in the full path:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME=/home/pi/lightshowpi
/usr/bin/python py/hardware_controller.py --config=overmech.cfg --state=on
```

Assuming python is in /usr/bin, of course.

I'd also put in an absolute path to `py/hardware_controller.py` but I don't know where you put it :)

Comment: I added /home/pi/lightshowpi to the beginning. That's where those commands are

Comment: I went ahead and changed the cronjob to see what happens with the code from the post above.  I will let it run its course in 10 minutes and see if the lights activate.  if not i will try the python code from the previous post.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I put this code into the lights on and off scripts.
#!/bin/bash
export SYNCHRONIZED_LIGHTS_HOME=/home/pi/lightshowpi
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/lightshowpi/py/hardware_controller.py --config=overmech.cfg --state=on

worked so far to turn the lights off

Comment: The script is failing to turn the lights back on.  I set cron to make a log file, but it is not creating it.  i did a whereis to find it and it had no results.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you should fix regardless of it being the culprit, by changing these your crontab should work.

First and foremost, like everybody else mentioned make sure your shell scripts have this or it's equivalent in your system. You can also redirect sdout and stderrr in your crontab by using something similar to this in your crontab:

```
*/15 * * * * /bin/bash /home/pi/lightshowpi/lightson.sh  2&>1 >> lights_on_log.txt
```

By using 2&>1 you'll be appending stdout and stderr to that file in the home directory for the user running the cron job, that way you can review the output and errors and figure out exactly what the problem is.

The most likely cause of the problem is that you're not using the full path to the python binary i.e. 
    /usr/bin/python 
Instead of just

```
python
```

One other thing you should probably look into is the fact that your command line arguments for both scripts use relative paths, and depending on what user the cron job is running as this may pose a problem. Either change into whatever directory the py directory and overmech.cfg file are in or make sure to also use fully qualified paths for those.

The last bit I'd point out (I saved it for last because it doesn't really mean much) is that one of your examples shows

```
/home/pi/lightshowpi/./lightsoff.sh
```

The **.** is redundant and not needed. Dot-slash is used as a means to abbreviate the fully qualified path to a file within the current directory since . expands to the current working directory and / helps construct the last bit of the path. In the above example you'll do just fine without the . and just using the complete path like this:

```
    /home/pi/lightshowpi/lightsoff.sh
```

Comment: This is what is confusing me here. I turn the lights on with the on script manually and it works. When the cron job starts to run the show the lights will turn off. The show will run. Lights will not turn back on. The on and off scripts are in the same location directory, same script but with the difference of on/off words. I checked the overmech.cfg to make sure there was not a post show and there is not. This is where my confusion comes in.

Comment: Have you tried redirecting stdout and stderr as suggested? That would definitely help figure things out

Comment: I had a busy weekend sorry.  I went ahead and added that to my lightshow.sh command because it calls on the lightson.sh in that script.  I will let it cycle and see what happens.